# scrapy User timeout caused connection failure

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to download images but got timeout error:

```
Retrying <GET http://www/***.jpg> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure
```

However, I am able to download the image with wget **instantly**. DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT (scrapy parameter) is set to default 180 sec, so this should not be the root cause of the error.
I have tried using scrapy with proxy and non-proxy, both gives me above error.

Comment: Post your image downloading code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are scraping multiple images (especially from multiple domains), then downloads will happen concurrently and each download may take longer when compared to downloading a single image from the command line. Try decreasing the [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) setting and increasing the [DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-timeout).

Check with `scrapy fetch URL` that you can retrieve the image to rule out a Scrapy issue.

Finally, check the differences in request headers (User-agent, cookies, referrer, etc.), some difference here could account for a difference in the response from the server. If you can find a header that makes the difference, it's easy to change in Scrapy.